# Copy emails from multiple GMail accounts (IMAP) to Outlook Inbox/.OST

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, aggregation

I have multiple GMail accounts and would like to be able to see all of my emails in the Outlook Inbox (the main .ost file).  I have all of the accounts setup to use IMAP and I'm applying the following rules to each account:

1. After message arrives, on this computer only, copy to the Inbox folder.
2. After message arrives, mark it as read (this marks the original as read while the copy is still unread in the Outlook Inbox).

This works well if I always have outlook running, but if my PC sleeps or if I read the email on my phone first then the rules do not apply.  Is there a better way to merge all emails to the Outlook Inbox?  I'd like to be able to preserve the read/unread status in the Outlook Inbox, if possible.

I have read a couple of other threads that suggest forwarding the emails to one account and then using that in Outlook, but that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current version of Outlook, it is impossible to merge multiple IMAP accounts.